# Coffeeify won't parse more than the entry file

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gulp, browserify, watchify

I'm quite a beginner with Browserify. I tried to integrate it into gulp.js with Watchify (for performance reasons) and Coffeeify. I tried at least five more or less different approaches I found in Google, the last of them being [an official recipe](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/fast-browserify-builds-with-watchify.md) from the gulp docs.

Problem now is the transforming part. I want to use Coffeeify to parse my code which is mostly written in CoffeeScript.

Coffeeify successfully parses my entry file `app.coffee` but when I require a `./foo.coffee` from there, that file seems not to be transformed which will naturally result in a parsing error by Browserify about unexpected tokens etc.

Anyone got an idea how to fix that?

Here's the relevant part of my gulpfile, mostly the same as in the link above, just with added transformations.

```js
var gulp = require( 'gulp' );
var gutil = require( 'gulp-util' );

var browserify = require( 'browserify' );
var watchify = require( 'watchify' );
var coffeeify = require( 'coffeeify' );
var source = require( 'vinyl-source-stream' );


var b = watchify( browserify({
    entries: [ './coffee/app.coffee' ],
    extensions: [ '.coffee' ],
    debug: true,
    cache: false,
    packageCache: false
}) );
b.transform( coffeeify ); // as described in the gulp docs

gulp.task( 'bundle', bundle );
b.on( 'update', bundle );
b.on( 'log', gutil.log );

function bundle() {
    return b.bundle()
        .on( 'error', gutil.log.bind( gutil, 'Browserify Error' ) )
        .pipe( source( 'bundle.js' ) )
        // I actually tried to pipe in coffeeify here (gulp-coffeeify as well), didn't help
        .pipe( gulp.dest( './js' ) );
};
```

Comment: I tried your setup and it seems okay to me (with the exception of `vinyl-source-source` being `vinyl-source-stream`)-- how's your folder structure?

Comment: Oh, yeah, that's a typo by me, sorry. Well, folder structure actually looks a little different from that described in my code, I simplified that a bit. But I think it doesn't matter because gulp obviously finds everything that's required from app.coffee. The original structure looks like /source/coffee/app.coffee, /source/coffee/foo.coffee, /dist/js, /gulpfile.js

Comment: The error looks like this: `foo.coffee` begins with a class definition, like this: `class Foo \n defaults: -> // do stuff \n ...` and naturally, "defaults" is recognized as "unexpected token". (`\n` are line breaks of course.)

Comment: still fine :-/ what versions do your packages have?

Comment: All freshly installed. gulp@3.8.11, gulp-util@3.0.4, browserify@10.2.0, watchify@3.2.1, coffeeify@1.2.0, vinyl-source-stream@1.1.0. I'm going to try if I get stuff running without using gulp, maybe I can cut down the problem a bit.

Comment: Sure, let me know. Here's a gist with the setup I have: https://gist.github.com/ddprrt/69fbd7bd03c697ef592f -- with `coffee-slash-app.coffee` being `coffee/app.coffee` ;-) versions look good, btw

Comment: Okay, since I got your gist to work here I found my problem. I abstracted my setup a step too far. `foo.coffee` actually isn't located in my `source` directory but in `/source/node_modules/foo` to make use of the easy to use node resolving and to be kinda "path agnostic" with it - just like `require 'foo/foo'`. It's obviously found there but still, not transformed. So... a) is there a reason that stuff is not transformed via node_modules and b) what would be the easiest workaround? Not using node_modules and writing a custom resolve method?

Comment: ...and with that knowledge I actually found the solution here. Thanks for your help. :)
https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/515

Comment: cool, great that it worked out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this was totally my bad. I abstracted my code a bit too far for this post so the actual problem wasn't reflected here:
`app.coffee` does *not* actually require `./foo.coffee` directly but requires `foo/foo` from a `node_modules` directory, just to make things easier.
Which was exactly the problem: Transforms will not apply to required *packages*. This is [intended behavior](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/515).

There seem to be two ways around that:

Solution 1: A browserify option called `global-transform`.
In the API it's used like `b.transform( coffeeify, { global: true } )`. This will apply the coffeeify transform to every required module.

Solution 2: Package-wise definition of transforms. That means: Adding something like this to each modules' package.json:

```
{
    "browserify": {
        "transform": ["coffeeify"]
    }
}
```

I decided to use the first one because my "packages" actually don't even have a package.json file, they're just in the node_modules directory to be easily accessible by browserify.